# Delete records of other users with OWD as Public Read/Write

Tags: delete, owd

I have a custom object "Position" and the OWD setting is set as Public Read/Write. On the Custom profile I have given Read, Create, Edit & Delete permission to the Position Object

When I try to delete records of other users with the same profile I get below error:

```
There's a problem saving this record. You might not have permission to edit it, or it might have been deleted or archived. Contact your administrator for help.
```

Can someone please suggest how to delete records of Other users without giving them any admin privileges on the profile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be above the record owner's role in the role hierarchy. As per the [Article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000327316&type=1) you will be able to delete the record only under the three conditions apart from having the OWD and delete permission.

```
The User trying to delete the record is the owner.
The User is higher than the owner in the owner's role hierarchy.
The User trying to delete the record has the 'Modify All' permission.
```

Comment: Thank you so much for quick answer!